# Salesforce CPQ: Amendment contract issue

Tags: cpq

I am trying to create an amendment on the account and I am getting the following error:
[image]

o Error
•  System Error.Cannot process contract because we cannot link revised SBQQ__Subscription__c anc1C0000001oonySAI to its  source record. Check bat lee revised record matches the source record.
•  System Error Class. SBQQ.PauseApexutilities: line 60, column 1 Class.SBQQ.ServiceRouter.executeService: Line 66 column 1 Class.ServiceRouter.load: Line 66, Column 1 Class.CPQContractAmender.load: line 4, Column 1 Class.

What could be root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amendment subscription had the wrong or blank subscription id in the SBQQ__RevisedSubcription__c field.  I have updated the original subscription id in this field and it is working fine.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, how do I identify the original subscription id?